# IFS + AND do not match together

Tags: microsoft-excel

Helo everyone,
I am trying to write a formula that says `IF` certain amounts are bigger or smaller than 0, then they have to have a certain output. The formula works fine, but I need to tell the system that the cell I13 HAVE TO be higher than 0.
If I write the formula like this I have an error message, it seems it messes up with the order..  can you please check with me where do I am wrong? Thanks!

The formula is as follow: `=IFS(AND($I$13>0)I2>0;-I2;(I2<0;$I$13*C2%);(I2=0;"-")`

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxL3O.png)

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact formula?  You have 4 ( and 3 ).  Delimiter ; or ,

Comment: What you are trying is almost like a mess,, general IF syntax is,, `IFS(logical_test1, value_if_true1, [logical_test2, value_if_true2]…)` , hardly seen AND?OR wit IFS,,, if you have situation like this better use `IF` instead of `IFS` !

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, the think is that with IF it is more complicated to me! I know it is messy, that's why I am asking for help aha :) I'll answer and I will explain better to Emily :)

Answer (score 0):

If cell I13 is smaller or equal to 0，and cell I2 is bigger than 0, what do you want to get?

According to your description, you seem to want the formula `=IFS(AND($I$13>0;I2>0);-I2;I2<0;$I$13*C2%;I2=0;"-")`

Comment: Hello Emily, It seems that is works! I basically want to have, if I13 is higher than 0, to have reported in the H column the negative amounts of the I column. If the amounts are negative, then H13 should be multiplied for a given percentage (in C2 n this case).
The perfect case would be that the amount in J5 wouldn't be greater than the one in I5, but I will work on it :)
The system is not yet perfect, I still have to try with several other variables, but so far seems all ok! Thanks!